# iCloud Drive Not Downloading to iMac Documents or Desktop

Tags: icloud, imac

For the last few months, files do not automatically download from iCloud Drive to my Mac Mini after they have been created, modified or moved using another device; eg my iPad.  Changes made to files in iCloud Documents or Desktop using the iPad are being uploaded to iCloud - verified because I can see the changes on my iPhone.  However, on the Mac, each new or modified file shows a "cloud with down arrow" symbol in Finder, but to get the file to actually download to the Mac, I have to force it by using "Download Now" from the right click menu for new files, or first deleting the copy on the Mac and then using "Download Now" for modified files. Changes made on the iMac are uploaded automatically.

I have tried to find help on Apple discussions, without getting any responses. I have seen some references there and in StackExchange to a similar problem, but so far no good solution.  Does anyone else have this problem and / or a solution to it.

All devices are running current release OS.